# how to lookup into dictionary with multiple values for single key

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have two different dictionaries:

- It shows the brand name and its type (i.e. Air is a brand  and shoes is type)

`D1 = {'apple': 'phone', 'samsung': 'phone', 'LG': 'TV', 'sony': 'TV'}`

- this shows the product name and the number of orders placed for the same.

`D2 = {'apple': 3, 'samsung': 5, 'LG': 1, 'sony': 2}`

I want to create a new dictionary (without using pandas) in such a way that it shows the most popular brand for a given type and the number of orders for the same. most popular is defined as the brand with the most total order. if two or more brands ( with a given type ) have the same number of orders, pick anyone.

I've tried to merge two dictionaries as shown below :

`{'samsung': ['phone', 5], 'apple': ['phone', 3], 'sony': ['TV', 2], 'LG': ['TV', 1]}`

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it. If so, how can I get the required data out of this dictionary?

the code I used to merge two dictionaries into one :

```
d3={}
for key in (d2:keys()|d1.keys()):
  if key in d2: d3.setdefault(key, []).append(d2[key])
  if key in d1: d3.setdefault(key, []).append(d1[key])
```

expected result : -

`{'samsung': 5, 'sony': 2}`

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and accept! In case you missed my edit, I've updated my answer with a very dirty one-liner, which you probably shouldn't use, but which I'm quite proud of! 

Comment: The title of the question is not related to what is written in the question itself. And the title is completely wrong. There is no such thing as a _"dictionary with multiple values for single key"_. There is always only one value. That value may be e.g. a list, but it is still just one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit late to the party, but I *think* mine's the simplest so far

```py
D1 = {'apple': 'phone', 'samsung': 'phone', 'LG': 'TV', 'sony': 'TV'}
D2 = {'apple': 3, 'samsung': 5, 'LG': 1, 'sony': 2}

most_popular = {}

for brand, type_ in D1.items():
    orders = D2[brand]
    current_winner = most_popular.get(type_, None)
    if current_winner is None or orders > current_winner[1]:
        most_popular[type_] = (brand, orders)

result = {brand: orders for type_, (brand, orders) in most_popular.items()}

print(result)
# {'samsung': 5, 'sony': 2}
```

For each brand-type pair in `D1`, it checks to see if there's either no entry for that product type (in which case we put this one in) *or* if this brand beats the current entry on orders (in which case, we update the entry with the new brand).

The line at the end turns this data into the correct format for the result.

---

### Edit:

Managed to flatten it out into a very dirty one-liner (not counting the initial assignment of `most_popular`):

```py
D1 = {'apple': 'phone', 'samsung': 'phone', 'LG': 'TV', 'sony': 'TV'}
D2 = {'apple': 3, 'samsung': 5, 'LG': 1, 'sony': 2}

most_popular = {}
result = {brand: orders for type_, (brand, orders) in {type_: (brand, D2[brand]) for brand, type_ in D1.items() if not most_popular.get(type_, None) or D2[brand] > most_popular.get(type_, None)[1]}.items()}

print(result)
# {'samsung': 5, 'sony': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit complicated, but this should work:

```
D1 = {'apple': 'phone', 'samsung': 'phone', 'LG': 'TV', 'sony': 'TV'}
D2 = {'apple': 3, 'samsung': 5, 'LG': 1, 'sony': 2}

categories = {}
res = {}

for key in D1:
    if D1[key] not in categories:
        categories[D1[key]] = [key]
    else:
        categories[D1[key]].append(key)

for cat in categories:
    currMax = {'brand': '', 'value': 0}
    for key in D2: 
        if key in categories[cat] and D2[key] > currMax['value']:
            currMax = {'brand': key, 'value': D2[key]} 
    res[currMax['brand']] = currMax['value']

print(res)
```

It prints:

> {'sony': 2, 'samsung': 5}

Explanation: The first loop creates a dictionary for every category with the brands in an list as value. The second one goes through all the category and finds the one with the maximum value. Especially the second loop is a bit verbose...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, seems I was a bit to late. :P

```
D1 = {'apple': 'phone', 'samsung': 'phone', 'LG': 'TV', 'sony': 'TV'}
D2 = {'apple': 3, 'samsung': 5, 'LG': 1, 'sony': 2}

#creates list of lists
mylist = [list(x) for x in zip(D1,D1.values())]
#adds thrid value to lists in list (source countities in D2)
mylist = [x + [D2.get(x[0])] for x in mylist]

#creates empty result dictionary
result = {}
#loops through unique value in dictionary on index position 1 (phone, tv's etc.)
for element in list(set([x[1] for x in mylist])):
    #temporary saves current winner
    current_max = 0
    current_winner = ""
    #loops through the lists in the list of lists
    for sublist in mylist:
        #groups the lists by skipping lists which are not in the current category(e.g. TVs)
        if sublist[1]==element:
            #checks if the current lists has a higher maximum value than the currently best
            if sublist[2]>current_max:
                #if yes, it replaces the current winner in the group
                current_max = sublist[2]
                current_winner = sublist[0]
    #adds the current winner to the result dictionary, then starts looking for the winner in the next group
    result[current_winner] = current_max

#prints result
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you. I did some modification in d3

```
d1 = {'apple': 'phone', 'samsung': 'phone', 'LG': 'TV', 'sony': 'TV'}
d2 = {'apple': 3, 'samsung': 5, 'LG': 1, 'sony': 2}

d3 = {}
for x in d1.keys():
    if(d1[x] in d3):
        d3[d1[x]].append(x)
    else:
        d3[d1[x]] = list()
        d3[d1[x]].append(x) 

MAX = {}
for brands in d3.keys():
    maximum = 0
    bName = ""
    for brand in d3[brands]:
        if(d2[brand]>maximum):
            maximum = d2[brand]
            bName = brand
    MAX[bName] = d2[bName]

print(MAX)
```